# How do I write a conditional statement (IF) with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, case

What is wrong in below simple query? I tried to google it but not found

```
IF 1 = 1 THEN
  SELECT 1;
ELSE
  SELECT 12;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a [`CASE` expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) which is standard-SQL method of implementing a conditional and supported by every major database,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 12 END;
```

Or you can use the [totally silly and proprietary `IF` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT IF( 1=1, 1, 12 );
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that syntax is actually valid; you can find similar statements in the MySQL documentation.

However, it's considered a *control flow statement*, and those are only allowed in stored programs in MySQL. You don't state that this is inside a stored program, so I'll assume it's not. If it is, please edit your question to provide more detail.

If you're trying to do this *outside* a stored program, see [Evan Carroll](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214031/116653)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

After checking what seemed to be thousands answers on Stack Overflow I found a work-around for me:

let's imagine we store a condition in a boolean variable called @DEBUG.

```
SET @DEBUG=1;
```

Then, dependently on its value, we may execute SELECT query.

```
SELECT v FROM some_table, ( SELECT @DEBUG as DEBUG ) AS DBG WHERE DEBUG=1;
```

The good thing is, that this conditional SQL query may be executed outside of a procedure statement.

And if comparison to the standard SELECT IF() statement it can return more than one result.

Tested with MySQL 5.7

Answer (score -1):

This simple query can't be run outside the stored routines as stated by chapter 13.6.5 of the manual. For the single queries `IF()` function should be used instead. `CASE` may be a bit confusing because the `CASE` statement and the `CASE` operator has exactly the same syntax, inspite of completely different nature.